# How do I retry entire activerecord transactions in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

How do I go about retrying entire ActiveRecord transactions in rails in event of a mysql connection failure for a few seconds?

So far I have gone about retrying just the last query that failed by overriding the execute method of `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter`

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
def execute(*args)
    begin
      super(*args)
    rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
      retry
    end
  end
end
```

This is however leads to inconsistent transactions due to which I decided its better if I retry the entire transaction instead of just the last query.

Is there anyway I can get the details of the current transaction and just retry it from the beginning?

Comment: If the statement is invalid retrying it indefinitely is absolutely a bad idea. What is actually occurring? Is it just one location in the code? Is it multiple steps and if so are they actually wrapped in a transaction? Please post the relevant issue because I certainly would not recommend monkey patching like this.

Comment: Ok, so basically if mysql connection goes away for a few seconds, I want my current transaction to completely rollback and retry from the beginning. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear from my question.

Comment: I understood the question however "entire transaction" sounds like a process. There are certain concerns around transactions and what an "entire transaction" actually means as further described in [ActiveRecord Transactions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) and more specifically in the *"Exception handling and rolling back"* section. So it is not as simple as just "retry". Thus my list of questions.

Comment: Oh ok! There could be multiple steps inside the transaction, multiple nested transactions even. My query is whether there is a way to retry the complete parent transaction from start. Like if there is any object holding the transaction's meta data upon which I can call a retry method or something.

Comment: maybe you can use `ActiveJob` for this, that way you can setup the priority of the job, also, how many times the job should be re tried, etc etc, more info here https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html